# Actively maintained Object Document Mapper (ODM) for Couchbase (alternative to Ottoman)

Tags: node.js, nosql

I am new to NodeJS and Couchbase and am looking for a reliable Object Document Mapper (ODM) for Couchbase. The most popular one, it seems, is Ottoman but [Ottoman's GitHub repository](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman) is not being maintained actively. [Its own Website](http://ottomanjs.com/) is out of date and I cannot find adequate community question and answers regarding my problems (I cannot install its package on my project error-free on a Windows system).

Are there any recommended alternative ODMs to Ottoman that are reliable and popular?

Comment: It doesn't seems that there's any alternative. Ottoman is created by Couchbase, and it actually had two minor commits lately - it seems that it's being watched by them, but maybe they don't have a lot to update?